# Does a dead-end world count as transitive and converse well-founded?

Tags: logic

If I can prove that a formula is invalid at a dead-end world, does that suffice to show that it is invalid on a transitive and converse well-founded frame?

Comment: You need to supply some context. What systems are you working with? - I'm guessing you are looking at Kripke semantics for some kind of modal logics, but I shouldn't have to guess! Also you should tell us something about what have you tried?